# How to fill up elements of dynamical array with structs from user input?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

My program dynamically allocates an array for the size of user input. (If user input is '5' then the size of my `prog` array is 5). Every element of this array should contain a struct.(The struct contains a name and the points of 10 different tests). In the end I would like to output these structs like this:

```
a
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
b 
4 5 3 2 3 7 8 9 11 12
```

My problem is that I don't know how to achieve this. The only thing I was able to achieve is this, with the program mentioned below (the last data I enter changes everything):

```
a
1 2 3 4 5 .... 10
b
1 2 3 4 5 .....10
```

I spent hours with this and I feel like I am totally lost.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct programming{

    char name[30];
    int partpoints[10];
};

int main(){

    struct programming *prog;
    int j,i,N;

    printf("Please enter the total number of students: \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    prog=(struct programming*) malloc (N * sizeof(struct programming));

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("Please enter the name of the student: \n");
        scanf("%s",(prog+i)->name);
                    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                         scanf("%d", (prog+j)->partpoints+j); //PROBLEM!!!!      
                    }
   }

    printf("Name of students and their points: \n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%s\n", (prog+i)->name);
        for(j=0;j<10;j++){
            printf("%d\t",(prog+j)->partpoints[j]);  //PROBLEM!!!!
        }

    putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you want the struct number to be ordered or what ?

Comment: You don't ask for user input to `N`

Comment: you didn't scanf the student number N !!!!!!

Comment: I have it in my first.Sorry I forgot to include it I edit in a sec!!!

Comment: ...and your program doesn't compile

Comment: I feel st**d now. Thanks anyway I edited and it should compile now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your nested for-loop you use `j` to index `prog` in stead of `i`, and you must pass a pointer to an int in `scanf`:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("Please enter the name of the student: \n");
    scanf("%s",(prog+i)->name);
    for(j=0,j<10,j++){
        printf("Please enter point %d: \n", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &((prog+i)->partpoints+j)); // no more PROBLEM now
}
```

Note: you may need to add a space in the `scanf` format string so it will skip whitespace and cr/lf: `" %d"` (I am not a scanf guru).